# Multiple Figures on same canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to draw multiple figures on the same canvas using tkinter Python when a button is pressed i.e. when first time the button is pressed I want to show image1 and when 2nd time the button is pressed I want to display image2 and so on. In Parallel to this I am adding the name of the images in the treeview which is placed besides the canvas. Also I want to have a feature that, when I click any of the treeview entry I should get that particular image drawn on the canvas and other images/figures should be there in the memory. Code used is as follows:

```
def canvas_pic():
    # asking the user to select the image file using tkinter "askopenfilename"
    canvas_pic.counter += 1
    tree.insert("", canvas_pic.counter, "dir"+str(canvas_pic.counter), 
         text="Image"+str(canvas_pic.counter))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(image)
    canvas.draw()

fig = Figure(figsize=(15, 2), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, padx=10, pady=5)
```

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

As suggested by "ZF007" the solution worked for me and the working solution is:

```
def canvas_pic():
    # asking the user to select the image file using tkinter "askopenfilename"
    canvas_pic.counter += 1
    tree.insert("", canvas_pic.counter, "dir"+str(canvas_pic.counter), 
         text="Image"+str(canvas_pic.counter))

    global dct_array
    if (canvas_pic.counter == 1):
        dct_array = {}

    dct_array["dir"+str(canvas_pic.counter)] = image as an array loaded above

def image_draw():
    rowno = 'selected treeview element'
    image_display = dct_array[rowno]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(image_display, cmap='gist_rainbow')
    ax.set(title="",xticks=[], yticks=[])
    canvas.draw()
```

Comment: https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-tkinter-basics-tutorial/ and ...show your code of what you tried thus-far...

Comment: Issue happening with the above code every time when I click the button, new image is added to the canvas overlaid onto the old image. Now suppose if i want to get back the old image like for eg. currently the canvas is displaying image2 on the canvas and if if I click Image1 in the treeview entry then how shud i draw image1 onto the canvas?

Comment: you need to create a numpy container that stores all images in an appending manner. That ensures position 1 is image 1, etc. Then a second function where your input is the number of desired image to show.

Comment: Thanks ZF007 for your kind suggestion...Your idea worked out like a charm....One new issue arose that is when I am clicking to a particular tree element the image is not displayed in the canvas instantly, but it is displayed after window resizing?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Post your answer as a new answer. You can then select it as best answer as well.

Comment: Thanks once again ZF007.... :)

Comment: don't post your answer in the question. Just as "new" separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by "ZF007" the solution worked for me and the working solution is:

```
def canvas_pic():
    # asking the user to select the image file using tkinter "askopenfilename"
    canvas_pic.counter += 1
    tree.insert("", canvas_pic.counter, "dir"+str(canvas_pic.counter), 
         text="Image"+str(canvas_pic.counter))

    global dct_array
    if (canvas_pic.counter == 1):
        dct_array = {}

    dct_array["dir"+str(canvas_pic.counter)] = image as an array loaded above

def image_draw():
    rowno = 'selected treeview element'
    image_display = dct_array[rowno]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(image_display, cmap='gist_rainbow')
    ax.set(title="",xticks=[], yticks=[])
    canvas.draw()
```